# How to create a stacked bar chart with values in Vega?

Tags: vega

I'm creating a custom visualization in Vega for Kibana. It should display vertical stacked bars and their values in numbers.
The "y" axis is the doc count and the "x" axis a time scale.

I'm not familiar with Vega and I first tried to display numbers on simple bars. I copy/pasted, tweeked some parameters and had this version :

```
    "marks": [
        {
            "type": "group",
            "marks": [
                {
                    "type": "rect",
                    "name": "bars",
                    "from": {"data":"table"},
                    "encode": {
                        "enter": {
                            "x": {"scale": "xbars", "field": "key"},
                            "width": {"scale": "xbars", "band": 1},
                            "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "doc_count"},
                            "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "from": {"data": "bars"},
                    "align": "center",
                    "encode": {
                        "enter": {
                            "y": {"field": "y", "offset": -5},
                            "x": {"field": "x", "offset": 0},
                            "text": {"field": "datum.doc_count"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

The result displays simple bars, numbers, the time format is good.

I used a "y"and a "y2" to be able to display both bars and text, but I can't add anymore "y" axis ("y3", "y4"...).
Idon't even know if it's possible to do what I want.

It want the chart to look like this example but with numbers :
https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/stacked-bar-chart/